# Beaglebone black "beaglebone-black-make-microSD-flasher-from-eMMC.sh" function does not copy the fstab file? Any way to inclued this in the clone?

Tags: linux, beagleboard

When using the "beaglebone-black-make-microSD-flasher-from-eMMC.sh" to make a sd card to clone beaglebone blacks one of the things that I wish to be cloned is the "fstab" file as we load our configuration files for some software that we run on these devices from the usb drive. I am programming a few hundred beaglebone blacks and don't really want to remember to go and change the fstab file on each one and possible forget one, it would be a lot better if I could have a fully configured device from just loading the sd card flasher. Is there any way to configure the flasher to include the fstab files? Also I couldn't find any documentation for what files are not cloned in a google search. Thanks, sorry if this is a really basic question, I am relatively new to Linux.